# Why does my input type image do a postback

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I have a very simple form, which has nothing but two small buttons in it. One type: hidden another type: image. The semantic structure:

```
<form id = "whatever" method = "post" action = "<?php echo $self; ?>" >  
<input type = "hidden" value ="whateverelse">
<input type = "image" src="www.someweburl.com/resource.gif" id="notsubmit">
</form>
```

The form looks fine as it ought to. The problem is that when I click upon the image button, it actually does the post back. It isn't really a submit button so not sure why the submit happens. I do plan on having it to actually submit, so have a jquery handler that does something like this :

```
$('#notsubmit').submit(function(event) {

event.preventDefault();
// do my business logic
// make some food 
// whatever else I want to do
$('#whatever').submit();

});
```

That's about it. The problem is the submit still happens without really going about executing the code inside the submit handler. I commented out the submit function but it still submits.

Any ideas?

Comment: Couldn't you come up with a more informative title?

Comment: This title is stopping me to take interest in his question...

Comment: Yay me, I read it and made a good title.  Why all 5 up-voters and Felix could not have done the same is a wonder.

Comment: Original title for this question: "jquery kbgfha fvkhjaf`"; hence I'm downvoting the question. The answer has to doing with the fact that you're binding a submit event handler on the button rather than a form; a form has a submit event, a button has a click event.

Comment: come on, that was a small mistake.. :(

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan you clearly did not read the question well enough, I did mention that the submit handler was commented out as well..yet the form submitted..

Comment: Taken down the downVote

Comment: @ParijatKalia And you did not read my comment well enough to know that `event.preventDefault()` can't prevent the form from submitting if it's in an event handler which is never called. A `type="image"` is considered a submit button in HTML. I never got around to downvoting the question, but whatevs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It isn't really a submit button so not sure why the submit happens.

It is a submit button. I quote the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1) about the `image` type:

> Creates a graphical [submit button](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#submit-button). The value of the `src` attribute specifies the URI of the image that will decorate the button. For accessibility reasons, authors should provide alternate text for the image via the `alt` attribute.

---

> The problem is the submit still happens without really going about executing the code inside the submit handler.

That's because the `submit` event is never triggered on the button, your handler is never executed and the default action (form submission) is never prevented. You have to bind a `click` event handler to the button instead:

```
$('#notsubmit').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

The `submit` event is only triggered on `form` elements.

Comment: yo..I just did this..the damn form still submits

Comment: Mmmh, maybe you have to call `event.stopPropgation()` as well. I'm not quite sure how clicking the submit button initiates the form submission.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#notsubmit').click(function(event) {
    // do my business logic
    // make some food 
    // whatever else I want to do
    $('#whatever').submit();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks, I also mentioned that I commented out the submit function in my jQuery code but it still does a submit regardless.